# Display content based on if user is logged in

Tags: scala, view, playframework, playframework-2.1

I would like to display different content on the same page based on if the user is logged in or not.
One way to do it would be checking in the view if the user is loggged in or not and then act on it. 
I was wondering, is there another way to do it? Or is this the best way to such thing?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to guess what did you try...

There are some ready to use solutions ie. [Deadbolt 2 - An authorisation system for Play 2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala) which contains ***also*** proper helpers for the views, implementing this into your app will allow you to check if user is logged on the view level (`SubjectPresent()`), and much more.

Check the [example app](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala-examples)

Answer (score 1):

I also use an additional solution (SecureSocial) but you can do what you want without it, by writing something like this :

```
@if(session.get("username") == null) {
// not connected
} else {
// connected
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a go to SecureSocial because I don't like merging files :D